# Problema conceitual com webService, como fazer um webMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-service

Boa tarde galera, estou com o probleminha aqui na hora da criação de um webMethod. 
É o seguinte, preciso trabalhar com três níveis, nos 3 casos preciso mandar para o banco de dados, segue a rotina de adição do lote...

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Adicione um lote")]
    public string Adicionar_Lote(string ID_Cliente, string NR_Nota_Fiscal, string DT_Emissao, string OP_Tipo_Lote, string NR_Cnpj_Faccionista, string ID_Status, string COD_Verificacao)
    {
        object DT_Status = DateTime.Now;
        int i = 0;
        string t = verifica_Lote(NR_Nota_Fiscal, OP_Tipo_Lote, NR_Cnpj_Faccionista); //se repetir esses, nao adiciona o lote novo.
        if (t == null)
        {
            string leitura = "INSERT INTO Romaneio_Lote (ID_Cliente, NR_Nota_Fiscal, DT_Emissao, OP_Tipo_Lote, NR_Cnpj_Faccionista, ID_Status, DT_Status, COD_Verificacao) VALUES(@ID_Cliente, @NR_Nota_Fiscal, @DT_Emissao, @OP_Tipo_Lote, @NR_Cnpj_Faccionista, @ID_Status, @DT_Status, @COD_Verificacao)";
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=seiren_dev.mysql.dbaas.com.br;Port=3306;Database=seiren_dev;Uid=seiren_dev;Pwd=S3iR3n@1973dev;"))
                {
                    connection.Open(); using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Cliente", ID_Cliente);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NR_Nota_Fiscal", NR_Nota_Fiscal);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DT_Emissao", DT_Emissao);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OP_Tipo_Lote", OP_Tipo_Lote);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NR_Cnpj_Faccionista", NR_Cnpj_Faccionista);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Status", ID_Status);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DT_Status", DT_Status);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COD_Verificacao", COD_Verificacao);
                        cmd.Connection = connection;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.CommandText = leitura; //aqui e executado a interacao com o banco
                        t = "Inserido com sucesso";
                        using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            dr.Close();
                            dr.Dispose();
                        }
                        string seleciona = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";
                        cmd.CommandText = seleciona;
                        int ultimoid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                        ids.lote.Add(ultimoid);


                        return t + " ";//+ ultimoid;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                return t;
                throw;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return t;

        }
    }
```

**lvl1:** Criação de um lote.

**lvl2**: de 'x' romaneios(que vai dentro de um lote)

**lvl3**: de 'y' peças(que vai dentro de um romaneio, dentro do lote).
*PS:Tenho a conexao com o banco de dados, entao tenho acesso aos ID's para controle de cada um dos leveis.*
Porém é necessário que seja feito dentro do mesmo webMethod.

É possivel chamar um webMethod dentro de outro? porque se sim, facilitaria muito meu problema. Pois irei receber um XML do formato:

```
<IDENTIFICAÇÃO DO USUARIO>
   <ADICIONAR LOTE>
      <ADICIONAR ROMANEIO 1>
         <ADICIONAR PEÇA 1>
         <ADICIONAR PEÇA 2>
         <ADICIONAR PEÇA 3>
      </ADICIONAR ROMANEIO 1>
      <ADICIONAR ROMANEIO 2>
         <ADICIONAR PEÇA 1>
         <ADICIONAR PEÇA 2>
         <ADICIONAR PEÇA 3>
      </ADICIONAR ROMANEIO 2>
      <ADICIONAR ROMANEIO 3>
         <ADICIONAR PEÇA 1>
         <ADICIONAR PEÇA 2>
         <ADICIONAR PEÇA 3>
      </ADICIONAR ROMANEIO 3>
```

Um resumo: Como vou saber quantos romaneio e peças o usuário quer cadastrar sendo que todos vão estar dentro de um lote?

Comment: Nao consegue enviar Json? Seria mais simples pra trabalhar com objetos complexos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está recebendo variáveis estáticas por parâmetro. 
Você deve disponibilizar o seu WebMethod com um objeto e o decora como XML.

```
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public class Lote(){
    public List<Romaneio> Romaneio{get; set;}
}
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public class Romaneio(){
    public List<Peca> Peca{get; set;}
}
```

No teu WebMethod tu pode passar o objeto por parâmetro. Dessa forma tu tem mais controle sobre o que está recebendo e consegue isolar melhor o teu código.

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Adicione um lote")]
public string Adicionar_Lote(Lote lotes)
{

}
```

Dentro do teu código tu varre o teu XML que agora tu consegue controlar a quantidade de itens recebidos conforme o teu objeto XML do parâmetro.